# draw a top border on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a horizontally scrollable `collectionView` and the thing I want to do is to draw a simple top border.I tried to do it like so but with no success and cant figure out why it doesn't work

```
 var hourlyCollection: UICollectionView!
 let border = CALayer()
 border.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
 border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: hourlyCollection.contentSize.width, height: 1)
 hourlyCollection.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //TOP BORDER ON COLLECTION VIEW
     let border = CALayer()
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.collectionVIEW.frame.width, 
     height: 1)
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    collectionVIEW.layer.addSublayer(border)

}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Yes using self.frame.width works but how do you update the border when you start scrolling past